# rlang: tidy eval with model formula

Tags: r, formula, rlang

I am trying to wrap two functions from the `interactions` package in a function and stumbled into some behaviour I don't understand. Both functions `interact_plot` and `sim_slopes` permit bare name or string and are evaluated using rlang, so make possible the use the ⁠!!⁠ syntax to pass variables instead of the verbatim names.
I use `enquo` and `quo_name` (I know `as_name` / `as_label` superseded it, but I am not sure of the difference). The first minimal function works as intended, the second throws an error as if it cant find the model formula, although it could in the first function. Reading [this post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/quasiquotation-inside-a-formula/14929/8) I get that using tidy eval with formulas can over complicate, but that it is still manageable. At this point I an not even sure if it's a problem with my use of quasiquotation (which I don't fully grasp) or a problem with how the `interactions` package functions work (e.g. under the hood it uses `enexpr` that is discouraged because it "loses track of the environment of defused arguments", but I don't know).
Any help is appreciated, as I am always looking for new examples to help me better understand tidy evaluation.

```r
library(interactions) 
library(ggplot2)

run_interac_1 <- function(data, out, pred, mod) {
  
  out <- enquo(out)
  pred <- enquo(pred)   
  mod <- enquo(mod)    
  
  model_formula <- paste0(quo_name(out), " ~ ", quo_name(mod), " * ", quo_name(pred))
  model_fit <- lm(formula = model_formula, data = data)
  
  plot <- interactions::interact_plot(model = model_fit,
                                      pred = !!pred, modx = !!mod)
  plot
}

# Runs as expected
run_interac_1(data = mtcars, out = mpg, pred = hp, mod = wt)
```

[image]

```r
run_interac_2 <- function(data, out, pred, mod) {
  
  out <- enquo(out)
  pred <- enquo(pred)   
  mod <- enquo(mod)    
  
  model_formula <- paste0(quo_name(out), " ~ ", quo_name(mod), " * ", quo_name(pred))
  model_fit <- lm(formula = model_formula, data = data)
  
  simple_slopes <- interactions::sim_slopes(model = model_fit,
                                            pred = !!pred, modx = !!mod)
  simple_slopes
}

# Gives error
run_interac_2(data = mtcars, out = mpg, pred = hp, mod = wt)
#> Error in stats::model.frame(formula = model_formula, data = dt, drop.unused.levels = TRUE): object 'model_formula' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>